# Optimize the query time with multiple joins and cross join

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with the given structure

```
cron_mails  --- it contains all mails fired for each job
____________________________________
| id | user_id | vehicle_id | date |
_____________________________________________________
cron_jobs  --- it contains jobs for new vehicle added by users
|  id  | user_id (sender_id)   | vehicle_id  | date  |
_____________________________________________________

 users
| id    | email | email_option | status |
_________________________________________


Select u.id as reciever_id , u.email as user_email, cj.user_id as sender_id , 
GROUP_CONCAT(cj.user_id) as sender_id , GROUP_CONCAT(cj.vechile_id) as vechile_id
FROM users as u 
CROSS JOIN cron_jobs as cj
LEFT JOIN cron_mails as cm ON cj.vechile_id = cm.vechile_id 
                          AND cm.type = 1 AND cm.user_id = u.id
WHERE cm.user_id IS NULL 
and u.id != cj.user_id 
and u.status = 1 
and u.user_type = 3 
AND NOW() > cj.date 
AND u.email_option = 1
ORDER BY cj.date
```

This query is taking a lot of time in execution.

Is there any other way to execute the same queries?

**Required result** is to find all the users which are not in corn_mails table with the same vehicle id but having same vehicle id in `cron_job` table

- Users are in 'user' table
- Users add some jobs and their jobs are logged in cron_jobs table with vehicle_id
- Now we need to find the users excluding the user added job from the users table and excluding the users which are in cron_mails table with same vehicle_id

Result of explain query is :

```
 id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
 1      SIMPLE           cj     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        138     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
 1      SIMPLE            u     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        983     Using where; Using join buffer
 1      SIMPLE           cm     ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL        41872   Using where; Not exists
```

Comment: start by running the explain  `explain select...` and share the result into the question.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Also, explain what the query is doing.  I cannot understand the intention of the query and it doesn't look correct.